# How to create Tensorflow dataset batches for variable shape inputs?

Tags: python, tensorflow-datasets, batchsize

I have dataset for image captioning. Each image has different number of captions (or sentences), let say some images have seven captions and other may have ten or more. I used the following code for dataset creation:

```
def make_dataset(videos, captions):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((videos, tf.ragged.constant(captions)))
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(BATCH_SIZE * 8)
    dataset = dataset.map(process_input, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)           
    dataset = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE).prefetch(AUTOTUNE)
    
    return dataset
```

this code is worked fine only when the `BATCH_SIZE = 1` .
when I try to use `BATCH_SIZE = 2` or more I get the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Cannot add tensor to the batch: number of elements does not match. Shapes are: [tensor]: [7,20], [batch]: [10,20] [Op:IteratorGetNext]
```

Is there a way to merge these data in batches without using padding?

Comment: check, https://stackoverflow.com/a/58529805/8143158

Comment: @ V.m, thanks, but the solution in the link did not work with me due to the data shape differences

Comment: what does `captions.shape` return?

Comment: @ V.M, as shown in error message above: in case [7,20] 7 is the number of captions; 20 is the number of sequences (words) in each caption. in case [10,20] 10  is the number of captions;  20 is the number of sequences. 20 is fixed for all and the number of captions is variable

Comment: My question was `tf.ragged.constant(captions).shape` returns (None, None, 20) or (length of imges, None, 20)

Comment: @ V.M, tf.ragged.constant(captions).shape =  (1300, None). where 1300 is number of videos in training set